# Another OSX Lion snag: no formula for libyaml

Tags: ros, macos, homebrew, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On my brand new today Macbook Pro 10.7.4, following the instructions [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source), it fails on step 1.2.2:

`brew install ros/fuerte/libyaml
Error: No available formula for libyaml
Please tap it and then try again: brew tap ros/fuerte`

The only warning I got from  `brew tap ros/fuerte`  was related to flann, which I doubt is relevant.

Thanks for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36928/another-osx-lion-snag:-no-formula-for-libyaml/) by [tom temple](https://answers.ros.org/users/900/tom-temple/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-06-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tom temple](https://answers.ros.org/users/900/tom-temple/) on 2012-06-20**:
I have reason to believe that this is a problem with my homebrew installation and isn't related to ros.  I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Support for Fuerte is still experimental.  I would recommend Electric on OS X for the time being.

As for this problem, there used to be a version of libyaml specifically for ROS, a frozen version if you will.  This strategy of freezing non-ROS formulae hasn't worked out so well, so the duplicate formulae in the ros-fuerte tap have been removed.  This is why you can't find the libyaml in the ros/fuerte tap.

You can simply replace this command with `brew install --universal libyaml` and you should be able to continue, but I think you will run into more issues shortly after.  You can continue down this path with Fuerte, or backup to Electric, up to you.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2012-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1